# Spring data repository integration tests pass locally but fail on Jenkins servers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, h2

I am fixing some old integration tests that are checking the behaviour of spring data repository saveAll() and findAll() methods. Some of these tests pass locally but when I pushed it on Jenkins, they would always fail. I cannot figure out why they are behaving differently. I can see exactly where the difference lies but I cannot figure out what is causing the difference in behaviour of `saveAll()` method.
I will put one of these test. I am pasting the relevant parts only, after anonymising stuff, so please don't worry about some obvious errors.

application-test.yaml

```
Spring:
  jpa:
    spring:
      jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always
    url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
```

```
public class Fields implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID", columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    private Long personId;

}
```

Note: No constraints are added here. The save entity statements later on in the test case shall pass.

```
public class Family extends Fields {

    public Family(@NotNull Long id, @NotNull Long personId, String group, String name, String value, LocalDateTime lastChangeDate) {
        super(id, personId);
        this.group = group;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.lastChangeTsDate = lastChangeTsDate;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="GROUP")
    private String group;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="VALUE")
    private String value;

    @NotNull
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "LAST_CHANGE_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime lastChangeDate;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface FamilyRepository extends CrudRepository<Family, Long> {
}
```

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FamilyRepositoryTestInt {
    @Autowired
    private FamilyRepository familyRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() {
        familyRepository.deleteAll();
        
        long total = familyRepository.count();
        assertEquals(0, total);

        LocalDateTime timeNow = LocalDateTime.now();

        Family family1 = new family(1L, 1L, "group 1", "param name 1", "param value 1", LocalDateTime.now());
        Family family2 = new family(2L, 2L, "group 2", "param name 2", "param value 2", LocalDateTime.now());
        Family family3 = new family(3L, 3L, "group 3", "param name 3", "param value 3", LocalDateTime.now());

        Iterable<Family> savefamilys = familyRepository.saveAll(List.of(family1, family2, family3));
        savefamilys.forEach(pp -> System.out.println("Saved: " + pp.getId()));

        Iterable<family> findAllfamilys = familyRepository.findAll();
        findAllfamilys.forEach(pp -> System.out.println("Found: " + pp.getId()));

        assertEquals(savefamilys, findAllfamilys);
    }
}
```

The test fails on the assertion stating that it expected 3 but found 2.
With the help of debug statements I put, I can see that saveAll() is not saving the first item in the list.

Running this on intellij gives me 3 insert statements and everything expected

```
Hibernate: select familyfamily0_.id as id1_5_, p
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from pr
Hibernate: select familyfamily0_.id as id1_5_0_,
Hibernate: insert into family_familyam (id, prod
Hibernate: select familyfamily0_.id as id1_5_0_,
Hibernate: insert into family_familyam (id, prod
Hibernate: select familyfamily0_.id as id1_5_0_,
Hibernate: insert into family_familyam (id, prod
Saved: 1
Saved: 2
Saved: 3
Hibernate: select familyfamily0_.id as id1_5_, 
Found: 1
Found: 2
Found: 3
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from 
Hibernate: select familyfamily0_.id as id1_5_,
```

Running this on Jenkins gives me 2 insert statements and 1 update

```
Hibernate: select family0_.id as id1_5_
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from
Hibernate: select family0_.id as id1_5_
Hibernate: insert into family (id, p
Hibernate: select family0_.id as id1_5_
Hibernate: insert into family (id, p
Saved: 2
Saved: 2
Saved: 3
Hibernate: update family set person_id=?, 
Hibernate: select family0_.id as id1_5_,
Found: 2
Found: 3
```

Again, don't worry about malformed names, I changed them

So where is it going wrong then ?
Let me know

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is causing the issue is the ID generation:
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
Although, I am not sure what exactly is different on a remote machine. Both have JDK 17

To counter this, one can modify the constructor and let the annotation generate the ID.
In my case, I didn't want to change existing code, so another option would be to modify the test data and provide IDs that are not going to conflict with generated IDs. Something like:

```
I am fixing some old integration tests that are checking the behaviour of spring data repository saveAll() and findAll() methods. Some of these tests pass locally but when I pushed it on Jenkins, they would always fail. I cannot figure out why they are behaving differently. I can see exactly where the difference lies but I cannot figure out what is causing the difference in behaviour of saveAll() method. I will put one of these test. I am pasting the relevant parts only, after anonymising stuff, so please don't worry about some obvious errors.

application-test.yaml

Spring:
  jpa:
    spring:
      jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always
    url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
public class Fields implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID", columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    private Long personId;

}
Note: No constraints are added here. The save entity statements later on in the test case shall pass.

public class Family extends Fields {

    public Family(@NotNull Long id, @NotNull Long personId, String group, String name, String value, LocalDateTime lastChangeDate) {
        super(id, personId);
        this.group = group;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.lastChangeTsDate = lastChangeTsDate;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="GROUP")
    private String group;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="VALUE")
    private String value;

    @NotNull
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "LAST_CHANGE_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime lastChangeDate;
}
@Repository
public interface FamilyRepository extends CrudRepository<Family, Long> {
}
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FamilyRepositoryTestInt {
    @Autowired
    private FamilyRepository familyRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() {
        familyRepository.deleteAll();
        
        long total = familyRepository.count();
        assertEquals(0, total);

        LocalDateTime timeNow = LocalDateTime.now();

        Family family1 = new family(10L, savedPerson1.getId(), "group 1", "param name 1", "param value 1", LocalDateTime.now());
        Family family2 = new family(20L, savedPerson2.getId(), "group 2", "param name 2", "param value 2", LocalDateTime.now());
        Family family3 = new family(30L, savedPerson3.getId(), "group 3", "param name 3", "param value 3", LocalDateTime.now());

        Iterable<Family> savefamilys = familyRepository.saveAll(List.of(family1, family2, family3));
        savefamilys.forEach(pp -> System.out.println("Saved: " + pp.getId()));

        Iterable<family> findAllfamilys = familyRepository.findAll();
        findAllfamilys.forEach(pp -> System.out.println("Found: " + pp.getId()));

        assertEquals(savefamilys, findAllfamilys);
    }
}
```